# Can't Reset PC with Win10 & No BIOS Access

Tags: windows, windows-10, bios, reboot

The other day, my desktop received the Creator's Update for Win10. Following a reboot everything started running slowly and using up serious memory. Following another reboot I was stuck at the circles loading screen and could not go further. This was ultimately the end for my PC. I performed startup repair, chkdsk, system restore, PC reset with my personal files in tact... Nothing fixed the problem of the loading screen allowing me to log in. My last resort was a complete reinstall of Win10.

Now, I'm stuck on a loop. The installation will always cancel and give me a message "Why did my PC restart?" And tells me to connect to the internet so it can install updates and try again. Again and again. And again. Nothing.

I purposely left out another thing I tried because it's my main issue just wiping from the win7 disk I have. Any time I boot and tap F12 or Del... I get a blank screen and no boot options/BIOS. I've tried changing DVI/VGA/HDMI in case for whatever reason it's my display but nothing. I should also add if it's relevant, my boot up time takes 1 full minute of my motherboard brand screen (with bios options). That doesn't seem normal.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: You may start from cleaning up BIOS stetting. Remove the CMOS battery. Then set up the BIOS  settings as previous.

Comment: Funny you mention that, I saw this on another article and literally just took out the battery. It allowed me to enter the bios due to the reset. Thank you! Working on installing win7 now... Will keep this thread posted with progress. PS I also removed my NVidia graphics card to ensure no video issues with my fresh install. I'm starting to wonder if there are related driver issues.

Comment: The Win10 installation was continuously restarting so I have been trying to use my win7 disk to do the complete reinstall. My machine is about 7 years old!

Comment: Compare [Windows 10 Specifications & Systems Requirements](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/windows-10-specifications) with your system.

Answer (score -1):

By removing the CMOS battery I was able to access the BIOS once again. I scrapped the idea of installing Win10 and will be sticking to Win7 for now. I've experienced too many issues with 10 to date...